# Can someone help me? Json bad string at line 20

Tags: json, string, syntax

```
{
  "suffix": {},
  "chat": {
    "Depreloid": "local"
  },
  "spy-mode": {
    "Depreloid": true
  },
  "last-pm-interlocutor": {
    "BLACKCAT12321": "Depreloid",
    "Depreloid": "BLACKCAT12321"
  },
  "prefix": {
    "Depreloid": "\u0026c[jfhkj] ",
    "Sovaqa": "\u00266[jrqkrq] ",
    "KorolSombra": "\u0026b [ljwljf] ",
    "BLACKCAT12321": "\u0026b [test] ",
    "Nikof2": "\u00262[Лfkwokfw] ",
    "Yra": "\u00262[fkffkfjfj] ",
    },
}
```

well, I tried to move brackets) in short, I want to fix the bad string error and that's it...

Comment: Remove the trailing comma(`,`) after: `"Yra": "\u00262[fkffkfjfj] "`

Comment: now bad object at line 21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove:

```
{
  "suffix": {},
  "chat": {
    "Depreloid": "local"
  },
  "spy-mode": {
    "Depreloid": true
  },
  "last-pm-interlocutor": {
    "BLACKCAT12321": "Depreloid",
    "Depreloid": "BLACKCAT12321"
  },
  "prefix": {
    "Depreloid": "\u0026c[jfhkj] ",
    "Sovaqa": "\u00266[jrqkrq] ",
    "KorolSombra": "\u0026b [ljwljf] ",
    "BLACKCAT12321": "\u0026b [test] ",
    "Nikof2": "\u00262[Лfkwokfw] ",
    "Yra": "\u00262[fkffkfjfj] "
    }
}
```

So basically the trailing comma after **"Yra": "\u00262[fkffkfjfj] "** needs to be removed and the trailing comma at the end of the enclosing object needs to be removed.